# 'readline/readline.h' file not found

Tags: c, linux, libreadline

I have included:

```
#include "stdio.h"    
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>
```

and my compiler includes the flag

```
-lreadline
```

but I am still receiving the error message:

```
fatal error: 'readline/readline.h' file not found
```

I am trying to use the function, readline();

Defined in more detail here: http://linux.die.net/man/3/readline

Comment: What os/version are you using?

Comment: What is the path that your compiler looks in for include files? (Typically, it includes `/usr/include`).  Does `readline/readline.h` exist in that path?  (eg, `/usr/include/readline/readline.h`).  If not, add the correct path via `-I`.  (eg, if you have installed readline in /usr/local, add `-I/usr/local/include` to the compiler invocation.)

Comment: @TimCastelijns 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: @WilliamPursell I can't include any local files that aren't reasonably platform independent as this has to be used on other systems, on which I won't be able to control what is installed.

Comment: Actually, I think you might be right @WilliamPursell, thanks

Comment: @timeshift117: If you can't assume that `readline` is installed on all the systems where your software runs, then you can't use `readline` (unless you can manage to incorporate the `readline` code into your program).

Answer (score 200, accepted):

You reference a Linux distribution, so you need to install the readline development libraries

On Debian based platforms, like Ubuntu, you can run:

```
sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev
```

and that should install the correct headers in the correct places,.

If you use a platform with `yum`, like SUSE, then the command should be:

```
yum install readline-devel
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, but when I removed the -lreadline it stopped working, so I had to put that back in. I am using clang to compile, not sure if that's the reason I had to leave it in. I'll accept your answer when the min. time is up.

Comment: @timeshift117 - you're quite right it does need to be in there. Just to *find* the header files you don't need to link anything, but to *use* the function you need to link the readline library. It's pointless to include but not use the headers so I removed that from the answer

Comment: Can You tell me what -dev means ??

Comment: @SurajJain **-dev** or **-devel** suffixes means sources and headers for DEVelopers. Packages without **dev** contains compiled binaries only.

Answer (score 3):

This command helped me on linux mint when i had exact same problem

```
gcc filename.c -L/usr/include -lreadline -o filename
```

You could use alias if you compile it many times
Forexample:

```
alias compilefilename='gcc filename.c -L/usr/include -lreadline -o filename'
```

Comment: The `-L` option is for specifying library directories, not header files.