# Failed building wheel for rpy2

Tags: python, pip, rpy2

I'm running `Python v2.7.8` and `R v3.0.2 (2013-09-25) -- "Frisbee Sailing"` on my elementary OS Freya 64 bit (based on Ubuntu 14.04).

I'm trying to install the `rpy2` package with:

```
pip install rpy2
```

and it fails with the error:

> Failed building wheel for rpy2

Down below I also see:

> error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

The full output is [here](http://pastebin.com/0HdaDbEx).

I've already tried:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev libevent-dev python3-dev
```

but the error remains.

I know `pip` works because I've already installed `numpy`, `matplotlib`, `scipy`, and other packages using it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the answer in [this post](http://sysads.co.uk/2014/06/install-r-base-3-1-0-ubuntu-14-04/). I just had to upgrade R from `v3.0.2` to the latest version available for my system (`v3.2.1`).

#### Step 1: Uninstall Previous R-base installation

```
sudo apt-get remove r-base-core
```

#### Step 2: Update Sources.List File

1. Edit the sources.list file

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
2. Add following entry (**for Ubuntu 14.04**):

   ```
   deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/
   ```

#### Step 3: Add the Public Keys

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key E084DAB9
gpg -a --export E084DAB9 | sudo apt-key add -
```

#### Step 4: Install R-base

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

#### Step5: install rpy2

```
pip install rpy2
```

Comment: This solution (upgrading R from v3.0.2 to v3.2.1) solved the same problem I was having on Mac (Mavericks). Didn't do Steps 1-4;  just installed new version of R and then `pip install rpy2` as root.

Answer (score 2):

It is indicated in the full output.

It has to do with how R was compiled and/or installed. Rpy2 is expecting a header that cannot be found:

```
   ./rpy/rinterface/r_utils.c:32:31: fatal error: R_ext/Rallocators.h: No existe el archivo o el directorio
 #include <R_ext/Rallocators.h>
```

Comment: Thanks lgautier, any idea on how to fix that given that I've already installed the usual 'dev' packages?

Comment: It was because of the R version. I have to update the check of the R version: https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues/291/check-that-r-32-is-used-to-build

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me because it's actually a header issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23085474/7049567

```
sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev
```

Or

```
yum install readline-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

apt-get install -y python3-rpy2

Answer (score 0):

For people wondering, in **Fedora**, you need to install this package:

```
sudo dnf install python3-devel
```

This will solve the problem if you have a **header issue**!
Pip is trying to compile `rpy2`, thus it needs a header file.
The header file is within this package!

Answer (score 0):

First upgrade the pip version

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Then install system dependencies (Ubuntu)

```
sudo apt-get install -y libssl-dev libffi-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libopenblas-dev
```

Then try to install again

```
pip install rpy2
```