# Readline Library header file missing

Tags: c, shared-libraries, readline

FIXED: i download readline through https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html
followed the install guide and it worked just fine

I deleted the readline.h file(not on purpose), i tried reinstalling it through brew, i even installed it through ports but now it just doesn't recognize it, leaving me with this message:

``implicit declaration of function 'readline' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]´´

in my .h file i have the following:
#include <readline/readline.h>

## include <readline/history.h>

and on my makefile i have
(CC) -o $(@) $^ -I$(incs) -I .brew/opt/readline/include -lreadline

Comment: If that is the first error message the compiler gives you, then the missing `readline.h` file is not the issue. The compiler would have complained about that earlier. Please show a proper and complete [mre] for your issue, including information on how you are compiling the code.

Comment: Also please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* build log/output into the question.

Comment: See if this helps: ['readline/readline.h' file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23085076/6865932)

Comment: Note that `readline()` is not a standard C library function.  If compiling with only standard functions, it should not exist.

Comment: it means you have not included readline.h in your C code before referencing readline

Comment: in my .h file i have the following:
#include <readline/readline.h>
# include <readline/history.h>

and on my makefile i have 
(CC) -o $(@) $^ -I$(incs) -I .brew/opt/readline/include -lreadline

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.